# Replacement of ArrayBuffer and DataView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, uint

I'm very new to core dart and I am having trouble in converting a piece of javascript code to dart. Please help me convert the following JS code to DART:

```
            password = "1234"
            value = [0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];

            arrPassword = new ArrayBuffer(2); // an Int16 takes 2 bytes
            viewPassword = new DataView(arrPassword);
            viewPassword.setUint16(0, password, true); // byteOffset = 0; litteEndian = true
            var uint8ViewPassword = new Uint8Array(arrPassword);
            var mergedArray = new Uint8Array(value.length + uint8ViewPassword.length);
            mergedArray.set(value);
            mergedArray.set(uint8ViewPassword, value.length);
```

There is no `ArrayBuffer` or `DataView` in Dart and I am unsure what are their replacements .

Comment: what is the issue with this existing code?

Comment: I want to port the above code in to DART, the above code is a javascript code @OMiShah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with this and then change it to your needs:

```
  const password = "1234";
  const value = [0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00];

  final passwordBytes = encodeUtf16le(password);

  final mergedArray = Uint8List.fromList([
    ...value,
    ...Uint8List.fromList(passwordBytes),
  ]);
```

[encodeUtf16le you can find here](https://github.com/dart-archive/utf/blob/master/lib/src/utf16.dart)

also, it may be helpful:

```
DataView(js) -> ByteData(dart)
Uint8Array(js) -> Uint8List(dart)
```

Comment: This was so helpful MAN, but the password is a String, but arrPassword.setUint16 (0, value) takes only int as value parameter in DART, do you have a workaround for it as well please?

Comment: @SiddyHacks just updated my answer.